# Python LIST functions not returning new lists

Tags: python, list

I'm having an issue considering the built-in Python List-methods.

As I learned Python, I always thought Python mutators, as any value class mutators should do, returned the new variable it created.

Take this example:

```
a = range(5)
# will give [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.remove(1)
# as I learned it, b should now be [0, 2, 3, 4]
# what actually happens:
# a = [0, 2, 3, 4]
# b = None
```

The main problem with this list mutator not returning a new list, is that you cannot to multiple mutations subsequently.
Say I want a list ranging from 0 to 5, without the 2 and the 3.
Mutators returning new variables should be able to do it like this:

```
a = range(5).remove(2).remove(3)
```

This sadly isn't possible, as `range(5).remove(2) = None`.

Now, is there a way to actually do multiple mutations on lists like I wanna do in my example? I think even PHP allows these types of subsequent mutations with Strings.

I also can't find a good reference on all the built-in Python functions. If anyone can find the actual definition (with return values) of all the list mutator methods, please let me know. All I can find is this page: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: First, the documentation you're looking for is http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: "As I learned Python, I always thought Python mutators, as any value class mutators should do, returned the new variable it created." – where'd you learn this? It is in fact very common to have objects with mutable state in Python, and lists are one of them. (Strings aren't.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than *both* mutating and returning objects, the Python library chooses to have just one way of using the result of a mutator. From `import this`:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Having said that, the more usual Python style for what you want to do is using *list comprehensions* or *generator expressions*:

```
[x for x in range(5) if x != 2 and x != 3]
```

You can also chain these together:

```
>>> [x for x in (x for x in range(5) if x != 2) if x != 3]
[0, 1, 4]
```

The above generator expression has the added advantage that it runs in *O(n)* time because Python only iterates over the `range()` once. For large generator expressions, and even for *infinite* generator expressions, this is advantageous.

Comment: Hmm I guess when working with lists to exclude it can be handy to do something like this: `[ x for x in range(5) if not x in (2, 3) ]`

Answer (score 5):

Many methods of `list` and other mutable types intentionally return `None` so that there is no question in your mind as to whether you are creating a new object or mutating an existing object. The only thing that could be happening is mutation since, if a new object were created, it would have to be returned by the method, and it is not returned.

As you may have noticed, the methods of `str` that edit the string do return the new string, because strings are immutable and a new string is always returned.

There is of course nothing at all keeping you from writing a `list` subclass that has the desired behavior on `.append()` *et al,* although this seems like rather a heavy hammer to swing merely to allow you to chain method calls. Also, most Python programmers won't expect that behavior, making your code less clear.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, essentially all methods that mutate the object return `None`.

That's so you don't accidentally think you've got a new object as a result.

You mention

> I think even PHP allows these types of subsequent mutations with Strings.

While I don't remember about PHP, with string manipulations, you **can** chain method calls, because **strings are immutable**, so **all string methods return a new string**, since they don't (can't) change the one you call them on.

```
>>> "a{0}b".format(3).center(5).capitalize().join('ABC').swapcase()
'a A3B b A3B c'
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither Python or php have built-in "mutators". You can simply write multiple lines, like

```
a = list(range(5))
a.remove(2)
a.remove(3)
```

If you want to generate a new list, copy the old one beforehand:

```
a = list(range(5))
b = a[:]
b.remove(2)
```

Note that in most cases, a singular call to `remove` indicates you should have used a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) in the first place.

Comment: The call to `list` is only needed on Python 3.

Comment: How does the use of a `set` differs from a `list`?

Comment: @stevenroose If you want to remove a specific element by its value, set will have O(log n), or even O(1) performance for that operation. Generally, the performance of list will be around O(n).

Comment: Python sets use a hash table under the hood, to it's `O(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

To remove multiple mutations on lists as you want to do on your example, you can do :

```
a = range(5)
a = [i for j, i in enumerate(a) if j not in [2, 3]]
```

a will be [0, 1, 4]

Comment: One remark: The `list.remove(x)` method removes the item with value `x`, not the item at index `x`, which your script does. For the `range()` lists that does the same thing, for other lists it may not do the right thing ;)