# why cannot invoke remove directly after split a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I wanted to remove a substring from a string, for example "a" in "a,b,c" and then return "b,c" to me, it does not matter what's the order of `a` in string(like "a,b,c", "b,a,c", and so one).

```
DELIMITER = ","
def remove(member, members_string):
    """removes target from string"""
    members = members_string.split(DELIMITER)
    members.remove(member)
    return DELIMITER.join(members)

print remove("a","b,a,c")

output: b,c
```

The above function is working as it is expected.

My question is that accidently I modified my code, and it looks as:

```
def remove_2(member, members_string):
    """removes target from string"""
    members = members_string.split(DELIMITER).remove(member)
    return DELIMITER.join(members)
```

You can see that I modified

```
    members = members_string.split(DELIMITER)
    members.remove(member)
```

to

```
    members = members_string.split(DELIMITER).remove(member)
```

after that the method is broken, it throws

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
        remove_2("a","b,a,c")
      File "test.py", line 11, in remove_2
        return DELIMITER.join(members)
    TypeError
```

Based on my understanding, `members_string.split(DELIMITER)` is a list, and invokes `remove()` is allowed and it should return the new list and stores into `members`, but 
when I print `members_string.split(DELIMITER)` it returns `None`, it explains why throws `TypeError`, my question is , why it returns `None` other than a list with elements "b" and "c"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-return-none-rather-than-the-resulting-li)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove()` does not return anything. It modifies the list it's called on (lists are mutable, so it would be a major waste of cpu time and memory to create a new list) so returning the same list would be somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983254/python-list-functions-not-returning-new-lists).

Quote from the [pythondocs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the default None. This is a design principle for all mutable data structures in Python.

Mutable objects like lists can be manipulated under the hood via their data-manipulation methods, like remove(),insert(),add().

Immutable objects like strings always return a copy of themselves from their data-manipulation methods, like with replace() or upper().

**Method chaining**

The next sample shows that your intended method-chaining works with strings:

```
# Every replace() call is catching a different case from
# member_string like
#    a,b,member
#    member,b,c
#    a,member,c

DELIMITER = ","

def remove(member, member_string):
    members = member_string.replace(DELIMITER + member, '').replace(member + DELIMITER, '').replace(DELIMITER + member + DELIMITER, '').upper()
    return members

# puts out B,C
print remove("a","b,a,c")
```

**List comprehension**
Now for clever lists manipulation (it is even faster than for-looping) the pythonians invented a different feature named list comprehension. You can read about it in [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions).

```
DELIMITER = ","
def remove(member, members_string):
    members = [m.upper() for m in members_string.split(DELIMITER) if m != member]
    return DELIMITER.join(members)

# puts out B,C
print remove("a","b,a,c")
```

In addition you could google for generators or look into [pythondocs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#functional-programming-tools). But don't know about that a lot.

BTW, flame me down as a noob but, I hate it when they call python a beginner language, as above list-comprehension looks easy, it could be intimidating for a beginner, couldn't it?