# Why does newList = list.remove(x) return None?

Tags: python, syntax

I have a list below and I want to remove a value and set it to a new variable. Why does it return None?

```
    aList=[1,2,3,4,5]
    newList = aList.remove(1)
    print(newList)
    #prints None
```

but when I do it this way, it works exactly as I would expect.

```
    aList=[1,2,3,4,5]
    aList.remove(1)
    newList = aList
    print(newList)
    #prints [2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: That method is simply defined to not return anything. Are you asking why that decision was made, or whether there is a method that removes an element and *does* return something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983254/python-list-functions-not-returning-new-lists

Answer (score 3):

In Python, when a function mutates an object it generally returns `None`.
Otherwise it returns the new object.

`remove` mutates the original object, which is why when you do `aList.remove(1)` and then print the list, you will see that the list is different.