# Why is this 'NoneType' error raised when performing a split?

Tags: python

When I run my code in this way:

```
What number? 4
1 (write) or 2? 2
```

First, this is printed:

```
['', '1233', '8989', '5\n']
None
```

Then the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Documents/explab.py", line 16, in <module>
split_2 = split_2.remove(split[3])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

From my understand a`split_2` should be a list rather than an NoneType, is this correct? Does anyone know how to correct the code so it functions as intended.

```
number = input("What number? ")
choice = input("1 (write) or 2? ")
if choice == "1":
 with open("r_3exp","a") as file_1:
    file_1.write (' \n') 
    file_1.write ('Here are some numbers : 1233 8989' + ' ' + number)
 elif choice == "2":
  with open("r_3exp","r") as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        split_1 = line.split (":")
        if len(split_1[1]) < 500:
            split_2 = split_1[1].split(' ')
            print (split_2)
            split_2 = split_2.insert(0, number)
            print (split_2)
            split_2 = split_2.remove(split[3])
            print (split_2)
```

Comment: Could you post your actual code?

Comment: `split[3]` is not a variable that you have defined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983254/python-list-functions-not-returning-new-lists

Comment: Where does `split` come from in `split[3]`? and use indexing instead of `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` and `insert` are in-place operations on lists. They modify the original list and return `None`.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> return_value = lst.remove(2)
>>> return_value is None
True
>>> lst
[1, 3]
>>>
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> return_value = lst.insert(0, 7)
>>> return_value is None
True
>>> lst
[7, 1, 2, 3]
```

This means there's no need to assign to the return value of `remove` or `insert`.

You are getting an error because you assign the name `split_2` to the return value of `list.insert` in the line

```
split_2 = split_2.insert(0, number)
```

which is `None`. Then you try to call a the method `remove` on `None` in the line

```
split_2 = split_2.remove(split[3])
```

which fails as expected.